# Is it possible to use TransitionDrawable in ViewPager as background and using more then 2 images?

Tags: java, android

I want to have an intro in my app. and I use a viewpager as an image slider that displays images on each layer and I want the fade in out effect when slides. How can i implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a PageTransformer in your ViewPager. Here's how:
https://android.jlelse.eu/creating-an-intro-screen-for-your-app-using-viewpager-pagetransformer-9950517ea04f